# Count strings in database table

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, count

I would like to know how to count choosed strings from database table. In one of my column are two strings called "correct" and "wrong". I have everything in array. I want to count how many strings called "correct" I have in column and how many called "wrong". I'm using sqlite.

Comment: If the only values are correct and wrong, why not use a bool?

Comment: Do you need a `GROUPBY` ?

Comment: I don't need Group By. To this column I'll probably add one, maybe two other strings. Also I'm using them to set image so it's easy for me. I'm new with xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try count(*) and a where.. something like:

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM yourTable WHERE yourColumn = 'wrong';
```

And another one to count the correct, or maybe you can subtract from the total.. I hope that helped!